# Can't access variables after webpack compilation

Tags: javascript, webpack

I can't access variables after webpack compilation.
I need it, because i'm using this variable to call function in onclick.

code is like

```js
function DetailClass() {
  this.add = function() {
    console.log(1);
    }
}

var Detail = new DetailClass();
```

Webpack including this code into eval()

And in HTML i call it like

```html
<div onclick="Detail.add();">Add</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't bind the events like that!

Are you using some framwork, like React or even jQuery? If you are using the latest, for instance, bind like so (in the JS, not HTML):

```
$('#your-id').on('click', () => Detail.add());
```

If you are not, bind like this:

```
document.getElementById('your-id').onclick = () => Detail.add();
```

However, if this is an exception and you really want to export something, you can set that to the window object:

```
window.Detail = Detail;
```

Comment: Yeah the whole thing where you put an event handler in an attribute is pretty old.  The event object is named 'event', a global.  The variables you use in the attribute have to be global too, that is, window.Detail etc, so if you're using modules, you have to assign them as Luan shows.  Much better to use  the 'on' functions as he shows, or I usually use addEventListener().  His first example is jQuery, the second one you can use almost anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

In your webpack configuration you have to specify `output.library` and `output.libraryTarget`.

Here's a guide: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library

For following configuration:

```
...
output:{
  ...
  library: 'MyLib',
  libraryTarget: 'var'
}
...
```

You will be able to use it like:

```
<div onclick="MyLib.Detail.add();">Add</div>
```